# simulate mouse left click on a target and then move mouse to the previous position in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, click, cursor

I needed to simulate mouse left click in some scenario in the code (c# .net).
this simulation must be done but it must be invisible for users. so when left click is going to occur I save cursor position. After doing left click I should set cursor position to the save value.
there is a problem.

```
                int save_cursur_x = Cursor.Position.X;
                int save_cursur_y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                int current_node_x = newGraphEditor.getCurrentNodeGlobalPosition_x();
                int current_node_y = newGraphEditor.getCurrentNodeGlobalPosition_y();
                LeftMouseClick(current_node_x, current_node_y);
                Cursor.Position = new Point(save_cursur_x, save_cursur_y);
```

When the last line (  Cursor.Position = new Point(save_cursur_x, save_cursur_y)) is removed left click happen correctly on the target position. But when I add that line, left click happen on a unknown position (or maybe left click doesn't happen)

This is **LeftMouseClick** method :

```
            //This is a replacement for Cursor.Position in WinForms
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

            public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
            public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;

            //This simulates a left mouse click
            public static void LeftMouseClick(int xpos, int ypos)
            {
                SetCursorPos(xpos, ypos);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);
            }
```

**Update:**
There is a selection delegate where target position set. this delegate should run exactly when you click on target. I think problem is here . After left click on target this delegate isn't run . After setting Cursor position to previous value delegate is run.  so target position doesn't set correctly because now cursor isn't on target.(Its position has changed)

```
ItemEventHandler<IModelItem> selectionDelegate =

                    delegate (object source, ItemEventArgs<IModelItem> args)
                  {
                      var tag = ((INode)(args.Item)).Tag;
                      if (tag is HostInnerNodeTag)
                      {
                          currentNodeGlobalPosition_x = Cursor.Position.X;
                          currentNodeGlobalPosition_y = Cursor.Position.Y;
                       }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SendMessage instead.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(
                      IntPtr hWnd,      // handle to destination window
                      uint Msg,       // message
                      IntPtr wParam,  // first message parameter
                      IntPtr lParam   // second message parameter
                      );

    public const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    public const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;       

    //This simulates a left mouse click
    public static void LeftMouseClick(IntPtr hwnd, uint xpos, uint ypos)
    {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, new IntPtr(xpos), new IntPtr(ypos));
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, new IntPtr(xpos), new IntPtr(ypos));
    }

    private void send()
    {            
        LeftMouseClick(newGraphEditor.Handle, 10, 10);
    }
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with threads. not the wrong position. I think moving cursor and left click has conflicted

Comment: Did you try to use this code `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, xpos, ypos, 0, 0);` ?

Comment: what is tagINPUT?

Comment: No my problem isn't solved. I still think problem is concurrency.

Comment: tagINPUT https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You can use SendMessage instead.